# Is it possible to show name for people picker in infopath 2010?

Tags: infopath

I have couple of people/group picker controls on a form (not directly tie to a list). they work fine but shows accountname (for example, jsmith). I like to show "John Smith".

I dont want to call profileservice webservice and do the filtering thing to get the display name.

However, form design from a different list (with people/group columns in it and configured to show name or you can show id or what have you) then infopath form shows Name not id.

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1):

STM,

Are you talking about attached photo scenario? I am not sure how to answer your question but it does seem like when you create a field or column based on people/group on a list then it gives your bunch of option as to what you want to display in the form where Infopath does not.

Can anyone please confirm this? I am kinda puzzled too.

From List
[image]

from Infopath
[image]

Comment: I am kinda curious too. Is Maria correct that people column when added from the UI behaves differently from standalone InfoPath form? I am surprised NO one can confirm this. I will be running into this situation in few weeks. I hope we get a reply from pro so I wont spending too much time. Sitesh

Comment: Indeed, she is absolutely right. You could actualy observe that by choosing to customize the Edit form with InfoPath direclty from any list having "People or Group" column, as the result will automatically be stored as expressed in the 2nd screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The people picker is a combination of 3 values, `DisplayName`, `AccountID` and `AccountType`. 
You are setting only `AccountID` in the rule where in you have to set `DisplayName` as well as `AccountType`. This will automatically set the PeoplePicker with the Name.